# How to force invalidate WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF app that also uses some native C++ proprietary library using `DirectX`. In some rare but deterministic cases that native library messes up the WPF `Window`. I need a way to re-render the WPF window even though nothing is changed in WPF point of view. It's just that library (that is out of my control) that has a bug, messing up normal WPF rendering.

I've tried methods like `InvalidateVisual`, `InvalidateArrange`, `InvalidateMeasure`, `UpdateLayout`. Even all those, but it doesn't work. One way of making it partially work is to change some property (like changing `Foreground` brush color by one bit) in one of the various controls in the window, but then the re-render is partial only.

One certain way is resize the window a bit, but that doesn't work when the app is in full screen mode that we support, in addition to the standard maximized mode.

Is there a way to tell WPF that even though nothing is changed, please redraw anyway?

UPDATE: The fix in the proprietary library was provided, curing the problem for me. But still it's strange that there is no good way to force repaint. The best workaround was to traverse all the visual children and modify FG and BG brushes just a little bit, forcing the redraw.

Comment: Please do not update the question with an answer. Just add the answer as an answer, it is perfectly OK to self-answer a question.

Answer (score 1):

I think `InvalidateVisual` is the way to go, but as you may not know the rendering in WPF is performed on another thread so the redraw will not be performed synchronously. To force a synchronous operation, you can use the `Dispatcher` to wait for a redraw:

```cs
// In your Window code-behind
this.InvalidateVisual();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(() => { })).Wait();
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for some reason. It looks like InvalidateVisual does not work if WPF is "sure" that nothing is changed visually.